# How to convert Swift.ArraySlice to Swift.Array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, slice

I am getting error from below code

```
if(currentArgument == "")
  {
      numberOfArgInCurrentFunction -= 1
      var lastExp = expressionStack.last!
      lastExp["ArgList"] = (lastExp["ArgList"] as! [String]).dropLast()
      expressionStack.remove(at: expressionStack.count - 1)
      expressionStack.append(lastExp)
      if(lastExp.count > 0)
      {
          let argList:[String:Any] = expressionStack.last!
          currentArgument = (argList["ArgList"] as! [String]).last! // ***Error on this line
      }
   }
```

> Could not cast value of type 'Swift.ArraySlice' (0x107ef4b40) to 'Swift.Array' (0x107ef2538).

Now want to know is there any way to convert Swift.ArraySlice to Swift.Array or a way to get last element from Swift.ArraySlice

**Edit- For Duplication**

if I try to convert  use bellow code

```
let slice = argList["ArgList"] as ArraySlice //*** Cannot convert value of type 'Any?' to type 'ArraySlice<_>' in coercion because 
let array:[String] = Array(slice)
currentArgument = array.last!
```

Comment: @MartinR I have edited question to explain that it is different from question you mentioned, Please let me know if I am wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The actual reason of the error is in this line

```
lastExp["ArgList"] = (lastExp["ArgList"] as! [String]).dropLast()
```

You are re-assigning the type `ArraySlice` rather then intended `Array` so already **there** you have to create a new array

```
lastExp["ArgList"] = Array((lastExp["ArgList"] as! [String]).dropLast())
```

---

And **never ever** check strings and collection types for emptiness with `.count == 0`. There is an optimized `isEmpty` property and don't wrap an `if` expression in parentheses in Swift:

```
if !lastExp.isEmpty { ...
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason for "don't wrap an `if` expression in parentheses in Swift" ?

Comment: It's just redundant. Unlike in Objective-C where it's required you don't need it in Swift. Less to type.